# Chrome/Edge/Safari - HTTP2 Requests getting stalled for every 6th request for upto 2 mins on IIS 10

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api, http2, iis-10

We have a .Net 5 WebAPI's deployed on IIS 10 server in a Window 2022 server. ReactJS front end application was developed to consume those WebAPI's.

While navigating through pages, every 6th request is taking upto 2 mins time to complete/provide a response and this is happening in Chrome/Edge/Safari browsers, but working fine on Firefox browser. On verifying the chrome developer tools, the stalled time is taking the 99% of the time consumed.NOTE: Each page has single HTTP request.

On further digging, we have found out that the IIS site has http2 protocol enabled. Once the http2 protocol is disabled, the application is working flawlessly.

For now, we have disabled the http2 protocol, but still wanted to understand what could be the issue with the http2 protocol enabled on the server.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: .NET 5 is end of life and known to only partially support HTTP/2. You will have to first upgrade to .NET 6 or 7, and then see if the issue remains.

Comment: As far as I know, browsers limit the number of concurrent connections. HTTP/2 adds multiplexing that browsers can send all requests concurrently over a single connection. The server may respond slowly.

Comment: I have upgraded to .NET 6 and still seeing the same issue. I have update the subject and question accordingly.

Comment: If I click on 'close idle sockets' from this link 'chrome://net-internals/#sockets' then the requests are completely immediately. I guess this is related to Web Sockets issue with http2 protocol.

Comment: If close idle sockets can work normally. Probably due to wasting a lot of time waiting for available socket. When you open idle sockets for testing, does chrome display the message Waiting for available socket?

Comment: No, chrome doesn't display any pending/waiting for available sockets in developer tools or network tab. We have not used any web sockets in our application as well. Not sure what exactly is happening. Tried with different SSL certificates and on different domains in Windows 2022 server and still the same issue.

Comment: Any solution on http2 with IIS server?

Answer (score 1):

We are currently facing the exact same issue. New Azure VM, Windows Server 2022 Azure Edition. Only difference is we started out with .NET 6 and our frontend is Angular 14.
I now created a new VM in the same environment with Windows Server 2019, copied the complete application folder over and only changed what was necessary and everything is working fine now. So there is some issue with 2022 and Chromium, but we have no idea what it is.
We only figured out it might be related to 2022, is because we installed it for a second customer which was also running 2022 and every other installation on 2019 or earlier was fine so far.